# Four fence logic puzzle

Tags: logic

Four men, live in four houses. Their last names are Mr. Locke, Mr. Key, Mr. Post, and Mr. Gates. Their first names are Joe, Tom, Ed, and Marvin. These men make four fences of different kinds for their houses. Find out the first and last names, the type of fence, and where every man lives from the following statements.

1. A next door neighbor of Ed installed a chain-link fence.
2. Mr. Post who isn't the man with the picket fence, lives in the second house east of Joe's house.
3. A man who lives next door to Marvin built a horizontal board fence.
4. Mr. Key, who doesn't live next to Ed, admired the lattice fence that his next door neighbor to the west built.
5. Marvin is not Mr. Gates.
6. Joe, who isn't the one with the lattice fence, does not live on the west end of the street.

Say the houses are 
H H H H

I can see that the second house (going left) belongs to Joe and the fourth one going left belongs to Mr. Post. Other than that I have no idea.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I'm not sure this is mathematics.

Comment: It's logic, which I would consider mathematics. Anyway I really need help if anyone has any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm not sure what degree of help you are looking for, I will simply give the clue I used, then mark my explanation of how I use that clue as a spoiler.

First denote the houses as $1,2,3$ and $4$ where $1$ is the westmost house, and $4$ is the eastmost house, giving us the following setup:

$$\begin{matrix}1&&2&&3&&4\end{matrix}$$

**Mr. Post lives in the second house east of Joe.**

> Therefore, we have \begin{matrix}\text{Joe}&2&\text{Post}&4\end{matrix} or \begin{matrix}1&\text{Joe}&3&\text{Post}\end{matrix}

**Joe does not live on the west end.**

> This gives us \begin{matrix}1&\text{Joe}&3&\text{Post}\end{matrix}

**The western neighbor of Mr. Key has a lattice fence.** **Joe does not have a lattice fence.**

> We first know that Mr. Key must live at either $1$, $2$, or $3$. Since Joe does not have a lattice fence, Mr. Key cannot live at $3$. Furthermore, Mr. Key cannot live at $1$ since he must have a western neighbor. Hence, Joe is Mr. Key, and house $1$ has a lattice fence \begin{matrix}1 (l)&\text{Joe Key}&3&\text{Post}\end{matrix}

**Mr. Key does not live next to Ed.**

> This tells us that Mr. Post is certainly Ed Post.

**Ed's neighbor has a chain-link fence.**

> House $3$ has a chain-link fence. \begin{matrix}1 (l)&\text{Joe Key}&3(c)&\text{Ed Post}\end{matrix}

**Mr. Post does not have a picket fence.**

> By process of elimination, Mr. Post must have a horizontal-board fence, since he cannot have a picket fence, a lattice fence, or a chain-link fence. Furthermore, this implies that Joe has the picket fence. \begin{matrix}1 (l)&\text{Joe Key}(p)&3(c)&\text{Ed Post}(h)\end{matrix}

**Man next door to Marvin has a horizontal-board fence.**

> This means that Marvin is neighbors with Mr. Post. By process of elimination, Tom is neighbors with Joe. \begin{matrix}\text{Tom}(l)&\text{Joe Key}(p)&\text{Marvin}(c)&\text{Ed Post}(h)\end{matrix}

**Marvin is not Mr. Gates**

> This means that Tom is certainly Tom Gates, and Marvin is Marvin Lock. \begin{matrix}\text{Tom Gates}(l)&\text{Joe Key}(p)&\text{Marvin Lock}(c)&\text{Ed Post}(h)\end{matrix}